# Is there a way to get matched results from values in arrays with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of tables which has numbers in them like shown below. I also have json data called edges which I am looping through to get source and destination as values and these are all numbers. I want to loop through my json edges and for each destination and source I want to check if both the source and destination exists in the array of tables and if they both exist I want to create a new array with the matched source and destination as keys. How can I achieve this using typescript?

The table data:

```
const tables = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

Now I am looping through my edges data like this to get my source and destination:

```
for(const edge in allEdges.value){
        const source = allEdges.value[edge].source;
        const destination = allEdges.value[edge].destination;
//match the edges and create a new entry
}
```

Now I want to loop through my tables data and match each source and destination. Basically if both the source and destination exists in the tables data I want to create a new array with the matched source and destination and then move on. The new array should like the below:

```
const newEdges: { source: number; destination: number }[] = [];
```

So basically for every source and destination that exists in the tables data create a new entry in the `newEdges`. The source for example can be `4` and the destination can be `5` and both of these exist in the table data and then a new entry will be created taking in 4 and 5 and if not continue the loop.

Comment: Please provide a plaintext [mre] suitable for others to paste into their IDEs, see your issue, and immediately get to work on it.  This should include some concrete input and corresponding output that covers the required use cases.  That'll help you get more useful answers more quickly.